# Nonpersonal they as antecedent pronoun

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Wondering about nonpersonal *they*, as an **antecedent** pronoun postmodified by a PP or a relative clause. (Of course *they* as a subject pronoun and *them* as an object pronoun are often nonpersonal.) Is it a known dialectal use now? Is it a marker of archaism? If so, when it did it drop out of mainstream use? Can anyone direct me to a treatment of this grammatical issue?

The OED currently has this one example under definition 6:

> 1630: The shops..nothing so full of wares, nor so rich, as **they** of London.

Nowadays we expect *those* instead of *they* (or *them*) in this position.

Comment: "They that go down to the sea in ships..." (Psalm 107). Definitely archaic, I would say; nowadays it would be 'People who...' or possibly 'Those who...'.

Comment: They is the pronoun for multiple "people, animals, or things", according to Merriam-Webster (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/they). It's entirely proper to use it for non-humans (including non-animals). "The shops..nothing so full of wares, nor so rich, as they of London." sounds archaic because modern English uses the objective/accusative ("them") after "as" rather than the subjective/nominative ("they"). But because of this, it's impossible to fully answer this question without you being more specific about a case where you're unsure about the pronoun.